# MongoDB - Compound Secondary Index vs Concatenated _id Index

Tags: mongodb

I am designing my database with MongoDb thinking in the scalability in the future. My main concern right now is about representing the indexes, as I have read, it is a crucial factor while scaling huge collections, in terms of RAM consumption, and sharding efficiency.

For simplicity, I have two different collections. A user collection which stores the user username, email, and some metadata, and a devices collection, that contains a device name, some metadata, and should be related with its owner. One user can have millions of devices (so it is not worth to store all in a single user document).

The devices collection should support queries in term of the whole device identifier by (username, device_name), or also by the username.

In this case I see some different approaches for storing the indexes:

1. Use a secondary compound index with username and device_name (in this order)
2. Use a primary index with and _id containing an string with username@device_name
3. Use an object in the _id field with both values {owner:username, device:device_name}

For testing this indexes, I have done some server load. I have created three different collections with this different alternatives and filled 5M documents. Some data:

1. I do not use the automatically generated _id created by mongo, as all my queries requires username/device. So this approach takes some extra space for indexing. The index size is `524MB`. It is efficient while querying both by user or by user/device.
2. As I am replacing the _id with my own string, the index takes less space. In this case `352MB`. I am still able to query efficiently by user (with a regex like /^username@/ the explain() reports almost the same results like in 1 in), and by the exact username/device.
3. The _id index cannot be changed to a compound index, so it is required to create a secondary compound index with {_id.owner, _id.device}. This results in a huge index size of `1059MB`!. Queries goes well as in previous cases.

So, I can discard alternative 3, as this is not so much efficient. Between alternative 1 and 2, I prefer 1 as this approach is more clean, but it uses a _id field I will not use. So at this moment, the winning approach seems to be the number 2, as it allows me query efficiently by username or username/device, and it also takes less index space.

Is there a good reason to not use number 2 and follow with number 1, like when selecting the sharding key? Is there something I am missing? I am new with mongoDB and do not want to have problems when scaling my schema.

Comment: Fair enough break down. The biggest hint here is that since `_id` is required to "always" be there, consider how a query optimizer makes a choice to use another index. If you can use thing you know is "always there" then why go off an do the work to find something else appropriate? Seems you have done most of the work listing pros/cons. It really should be just a matter of logically working through those to find your answer.